# Does a using declaration of a template specialization always cause its implicit instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I understand that it is illegal to do the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct will_get_explicitly_specialized {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T>
struct ordinary_template {
    using type = typename will_get_explicitly_specialized<T>::type;
};

ordinary_template<int> x;

template<>
struct will_get_explicitly_specialized<int> {
     using type = int;
};
```

This will (hopefully, as I believe it is not required) generate an error like the following:

```
<source>:16:8: error: specialization of 'will_get_explicitly_specialized<int>' after instantiation
   16 | struct will_get_explicitly_specialized<int> {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:8: error: redefinition of 'struct will_get_explicitly_specialized<int>'
<source>:4:8: note: previous definition of 'struct will_get_explicitly_specialized<int>'
    4 | struct will_get_explicitly_specialized {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

This aligns with my understanding that all explicit specializations of `will_get_explicitly_specialized` need to come before any implicit instantiations of `will_get_explicitly_specialized`, and the declaration of `ordinary_template<int> x` necessarily causes instantiation of `ordinary_template<int>`, and that appears in turn to require implicit instantiation of `will_get_explicitly_specialized<int>` due to the `using type =`  statement.

Interestingly though, a top-level `using` statement at that position in the code does not raise a diagnostic (in the same environment):

```
template<typename T>
struct will_get_explicitly_specialized {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T>
struct ordinary_template {
    using type = typename will_get_explicitly_specialized<T>::type;
};

using ot_int = ordinary_template<int>;

template<>
struct will_get_explicitly_specialized<int> {
     using type = int;
};

ot_int x;
```

I would like to know if this is still illegal (but perhaps no diagnostic is issued and one is not required), or whether this sort of `using` statement is somehow different from the one in `ordinary_template` such that it does not count as causing an implicit instantiation of `will_get_explicitly_specialized`.

In either event, what is the language that makes clear whether/when a specialization of a template in a `using` statement results in implicit instantiation?

It feels intuitively like it should be ok to say `using ot_int = ordinary_template<int>` before all the specializations are in, because until you actually use `ot_int` somehow, nothing has really happened such that `ordinary_template<int>` needs to exist. But of course just because it feels that way, it doesn't make it true!

Comment: Just for fun look here : https://cppinsights.io/s/43ec9f38 and press the play button. 
You can then see what C++ instantiates and does not instantiate.  The using statement is just an alias and as you can see it will not lead to instantiation (until you use the alias)

Answer (score 2):

> This will (hopefully, as I believe it is not required) generate an error like the following:

Technically the first program is IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required) according to [[temp.expl.spec]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/temp.expl.spec#7.sentence-1) because there is no declaration of the explicit specialization of `will_get_explicitly_specialized<int>` reachable from `ordinary_template<int> x;` which however would cause implicit instantiation of that same specialization.

So a compiler is technically not required to diagnose the issue. There is no requirement imposed on the compiler for this program.

---

Simply naming a specialization with a template-id doesn't cause it to be implicitly instantiated. The relevant section of the standard in [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/temp.inst#2.sentence-1) says:

> Unless a class template specialization is a declared specialization, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.

In a definition of a variable such as

```
ordinary_template<int> x;
```

or

```
ot_int x;
```

the type of the variable must always be complete. This implies in both cases that `ordinary_template<int>` must be implicitly instantiated at this point (if it hasn't already been instantiated beforehand).

However, simply declaring a type alias has no requirement on the type being complete and neither does the declaration have any different semantic if the type is incomplete.

So, simply aliasing a class template specialization will never cause it to be implicitly instantiated. Your second program therefore doesn't violate the rule mentioned above and is well-formed with defined behavior (lack of `main` aside). `ot_int::type` will be `int` as required by the explicit specialization.

Comment: You should cite the section of the standard that specifies when a class template specialization is implicitly instantiated (not just paraphrase it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the delay following up. I think I'm fairly convinced by your argument and cites, but with two follow-up concerns. First and foremost, what is different about the `using type = ...` statement inside `ordinary_template` such that it runs afoul of these rules? Second, the language "completeness ... affects the semantics of the program" feels pretty vague. What exactly determines what constructs do and do not affect the program semantics? The language from the standard here feels fairly open to interpretation, on first encounter.

Comment: @acm That `using` declaration is doing name lookup into `will_get_explicitly_specialized<T>` for which the definition of that class is required, i.e. the type needs to be complete. So whenever the class containing it is instantiated for some `T`, `will_get_explicitly_specialized<T>` will be implicitly instantiated with the same `T` and at the same point at which the enclosing class specialization is instantiated.

Comment: @acm It isn't vague. It just means that if the standard somewhere else has a rule of the form "if T is complete, then [...], othwise [...]", whenever that rule would need to be applied, then `T` will be implicitly instantiated (if possible and not already instantiated earlier). For example: A C-style cast `(T*)x` where `T` is a class type and `x` an (unqualified) class type pointer could be a `static_cast`, but only if the type of `*x` is related to `T` by inheritance. Otherwise it is a `reinterpret_cast` with different semantics. If `T` is incomplete, then `static_cast` isn't possible.